# Adding parameter to request() stream

Tags: node.js, api, http, express, request

I'm trying to proxy / stream api call for reCaptcha through my server as t requires secret passed in with a post call, at the moment it's as simple as:

```
app.post('/captcha', (req, res) => {
  const url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
  // Add parameter 'secret' with value config.CAPTCHA_SECRET here
  req.pipe(request({ url })).pipe(res)
})
```

The commented out line is a bit I am struggling with at the moment, where I need to add additional parameter to the call while still keeping all that are already in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `request.post`:

```
req.post(
    'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    { secret: config.CAPTCHA_SECRET },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

From [docs](https://github.com/request/request#forms):

> request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}}) // or
>   request.post('http://service.com/upload').form({key:'value'}) // or
>   request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', form: {key:'value'}},
>   function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ })